# Why is a "You'll need a new app to open this localhost" popup being displayed when debugging my asp.net core 2.0 app in Edge?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-edge, asp.net-core-2.0, razorengine

I'm simply entering "MyMessages/Index" after localhost:51531/ and this popup is being displayed. Seems super weird to me but probably something simple.

So I try to navigate to `localhost:51531/MyMessages/Index` in Edge.

The controller is `public class MyMessagesController : Controller`

The controller action is just:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

**This does not happen in IE11**

Comment: Your question seems missing! What is the controller name?

Comment: Can you show the View name "Index" in "MyMessages" Folder?

Comment: @Coding I cannot take as screenshot since it is on my intranet computer. I can assure you the filepath is ../Views/MyMessages/Index.cshtml

Comment: What happens if instead you go to `http://localhost:51531/MyMessages/Index`? Or `http://localhost:51531/MyMessages/`?

Comment: Try prepending `http://` to that URL. It seems to be parsing `localhost` as the protocol, which is why it can't find an app to open it with - there is _probably_ no application on your machine registered for the "`localhost` protocol".

Comment: @mjwills That worked :) thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The issue is that you have left the [scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme(v=vs.110).aspx) off the start of the URL. *Some browsers will **infer**
 it in certain circumstances, but not all browsers will infer it all the time.*

Instead of:

```
localhost:51531/MyMessages/Index
```

Try:

```
http://localhost:51531/MyMessages/Index
```

Answer (score 6):

Try prepending `http://` to that URL. Edge seems to be parsing `localhost` as the [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), which is why Windows can't find an app to open it with - there is *probably* no application on your machine registered to `localhost`.

```
http://localhost:51531/MyMessages/Index
```

It might seem like a no-brainer to infer `http://`, but keep in mind that navigating to e.g. `file://C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\document.txt` in any web browser *will* open the file - so when the browser sees something that *looks* like a URI scheme (like `localhost:51531`), it does make sense to assume it is one.

The "You'll need a new app to open this" dialog appears when a URL is entered with a scheme that has not been registered to an application. An example of a custom application-specific scheme is the `steam://[appid]` URL scheme, or the `mailto://[address]` scheme often used by i.e. Outlook.

(See also [What is a URI scheme?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294588/what-is-a-uri-scheme))

Comment: this worked for me, in my case I was debugging an app and wanted to force a clean load of the page so I just went to address bar and hit [ENTER], didn't work until I manually added the http:// prefix, quite annoying!

Answer (score 1):

The simple option of prefixing http seems fine but let's say you hit Ctrl+R (which developers do often) then for weird reason it still pops up applications to open which is annoying. 
I was able to get it work by adding dns entry (etc/hosts) so that "Edge" must know now what localhost is.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```